# Android Splash Screen API Slow on some devices

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I've implemented the new Android Splash Screen API with a `RoutingActivity` since it isn't feasible for my app to break it down to a single activity application. The recommended way, as per the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate#prevent_the_custom_activity_from_displaying) is as below:

```
class RoutingActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Keep the splash screen visible for this Activity
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
        startSomeNextActivity()
        finish()
     }
```

This seems to work well on some devices but with others, it stays on for over 8-12secs sometimes. I added a log with a timer after on create just to see when execution occurs. It was reached after 5secs.

Is there something that can be done to make the splash screen complete much faster?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#set-theme try setting the duration in the xml file.

Comment: @Samuel Duration is set to 500ms but it doesn't change much.

Comment: oh i see, got the same problem on my app too.